# Phone locked - Vysor is hiding the keyboard on my phone

Tags: android, keyboard, remote-debugging, locked

I used Vysor a couple of days ago to test an app I created. The next day, my keyboard suddenly changes into Vysor's hiding the keyboard on the screen. Good thing I was at home to recon the phone on my computer so I was able to unlock the phone and change back to my default keyboard. I'm kind of upset that I absentmindedly turn off the remote  debugging thinking I won't be needing it on for the mean time. Yesterday a notification pops in saying "Vysor is hiding your keyboard". Until now I'm not able to unlock my phone! I already boot up the phone, tried otg cable and used bluetooth keyboard but there is no use. I can't use vysor or any other app as remote debugging is turned off. I still can't get in! I can't reset the phone to factory default as I have important files inside. Can someone please help me.

Comment: why do you need a keyboard to unlock your phone?

Comment: Because there is no keyboard showing up on my android phone. How am i going to unlock it? I've read that I can try using external keyboard but that doesn't work as you need to go to phone setting to allow it to connect. I'm out of option.

Comment: I unlock my phone with a finger swipe, that deos not need a keyboard. So the question is the same `why do you need a keyboard to unlock your phone?`

Comment: So, you have a numerical pin code? (Nothing weird in that.) One possibility could be a regular wired USB keyboard via a USB OTG cable. But sounds like this really isn't a programming question and shouldn't be on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, fingerprint is disabled. I am just wondering if anyone can help me with unlocking my phone (be it with a program or an app or a software - anything. I've read articles on the internet and watched videos about removing frp lock and using adb which I think APP DEVELOPERS (especially android) are aware of. Following them is also risky---- Sooo yes I need HELP.

Comment: I did try the keyboard and as I said it doesn't work. And by the way, is this site only for coding issues?????

Comment: You said you tried a Bluetooth keyboard. Regular wired USB keyboards (or mice) don't require any setup, I believe. Or keyboards/mice with their own USB dongle. You just plug them in. And yes, this is coding site. Test automation, toolchain and building, continuous integration and whatnot questions may also be on topic. Use of the ADB too, why not.

Comment: Yes i did try the keyboard with the cable too.

Comment: How about — does anyone here knows how to enable remote debugging while the phone is locked???

Comment: You might also find relevant discussions and/or get answers at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/). If not for unlocking the device, then at least for backing up any important content on the device.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. I set my phone to emmergency mode disabling running apps such as vysor.

Answer (score 1):

try using the "safe mode" for your smartphone then uninstall vysor, it works for me. After turn off your phone and then turn it on.

Comment: Is safe mode and emergency mode the same? If so, this is already answered in the comments.